# Who composed "Lingashtakam" & what are the "Asta Daridras" mentioned there in it?

Tags: shiva, scripture, shiva-lingam

The Lingashtakam is one of the most popular Ashtakams(a Stotram with 8 verses) dedicated to Lord Shiva which praises Him in the abstract "Lingam" form.

You can read it  [here](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_shiva-lingashtakam.php).

However,till date,i have never  encountered any website that provides any information about the author of this beautiful octet.

Question 1-Who composed the Lingashtakam?

Verse 7 of the said Ashtakam ends with the following line :

> **Asta Daridra** Vinasita Lingam,Tat Pranamami Sada Siva Lingam,

which refers to the Asta Daridras or the 8 types of poverties.

Question 2-What are these 8 types(forms) of poverties?

Comment: I think Adi Shankara composed Lingastakam afaik. Will provide you scriptural evidence.

Comment: Good question. I've also [visited](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/lingashh.html?lang=sa) but didn't find the author. Some says he was Adi Shankara but can't justify. For 8 kind of poverty, there is one [stuff](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110524041736AAVpfNc) but scriptural reference/commentary is recommended

Comment: I found some Google books for Lingastakam which say it was written by Adi Shankara. [1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XgPtBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&dq=lingastakam&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=lingastakam&f=false), [2](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LpLmAAAAMAAJ&q=lingastakam&dq=lingastakam&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y) and [3](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kYbXAAAAMAAJ&q=lingastakam&dq=lingastakam&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y). I searched for scriptural evidence for Asta daridras but couldn't find any.

Comment: @AnilKumar Good finds.

Comment: If ashta Aishwaryas are Anima, Mahima, Laghima, Garima,Prapti , Vasitwa,Prakamya and Isitwa then what is ashta daridras.
May be opposite of that.

Comment: Neelothapala, so the Ashta Siddhis are  the Ashta Aishwaryas?

Comment: BTw ur thinking mite be indicative of what is true..For ex we have the Ashta Lakshmis..So the opposites of these 8 may be the Ashta Daridras..

Answer (score 2):

**As per Swami Avimukteshwaranand Saraswati**, who is currently the Incumbent Shankaracharya of the [Uttarāmnāya Śrī Jyotish Pītham or Jyotir Math](https://shreejyotirmathah.org/) (situated in Uttarakhand; one of the four cardinal pitham established by Sri Adi Shankaracharya). - **the asht-daaridras are nothing but the opposite of the ashta-Lakshmis (or asht-aishvaryas).**

> Reference - See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MSfeRsEWMI)

[This blog-site](https://www.bolochant.com/resources/library/lingastakam) (which is perhaps by an amateur follower of the Sanatan-dharm but nevertheless), besides giving other interpretation, also succinctly summarizes the authoritative commentary by the Jyotir-math's Shankaracharya as linked in the video above -

> In some traditions, the eight forms of poverty (aṣṭadaridra) are as
> follows:
>
> a. annadaridra — lack of food
>
> b. vastradaridra — lack of clothing
>
> c. nivāsadaridra — lack of shelter
>
> d. bhūmidaridra — lack of territory
> (either one’s own plot of land, or more broadly, a lack of country)
>
> e. santatīdaridra — lack of family or progeny
>
> f. sampattidaridra — lack of
> good fortune
>
> g. āpteṣṭadaridra — lack of the fruits of worship (āpta,
> “reach, attain”; iṣṭa, “worshipped with sacrifices”)
>
> h. mitraparivāradaridra — lack of a community of friends.
>
> **Some lists also
> include jñānadaridra (lack of wisdom), and vivekadaridra (lack of
> discrimination**, the ability to discern the spiritual from the
> material).
>
> **Other traditions associate the eight poverties with the eight forms of
> the goddess of wealth, Lakṣmī**.
>
> Each form of Lakṣmī embodies a
> particular kind of wealth, and the eight forms of poverty are the lack
> of those types of wealth. The eight forms of Lakṣmī are as follows:
>
> - ādilakṣmī — abundance of spiritual merit
> - dhānyalakṣmī — abundance of
>   grain (food)
> - vīralakṣmī — abundance of bravery
> - gajalakṣmī — abundance
>   of livestock
> - santanalakṣmī — abundance of progeny
> - vijayalakṣmī —
>   abundance of victory (in overcoming obstacles)
> - vidyālakṣmī — abundance
>   of knowledge
> - dhanalakṣmī — abundance of money

Thus asht-daaridras maybe inferred as to be antonyms of the opulences signified by the asht-Lakshmis as follows -

1. Spiritual Poverty.
2. Food Poverty.
3. Courage Poverty.
4. Livestock Poverty.
5. Progeny Poverty
6. Success Poverty
7. Knowledge and Wisdom Poverty
8. Monetary Poverty.

Regarding the authorship of the Lingashtakam, several researchers both traditional or heterodox, assign it to Shri Adi Shankaracharya, but then again, it can't be proved in 100% terms. At best. we can say that sometimes the Lingashtakam's authorship is attributed to Adi-Sankara by some scholars while others assign it to unknown/untraceable authorship too.
Nevertheless, it is a beautiful composition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.